# PHP Inner HTML block style is overriding entire website's style

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display an HTML email by inserting the entire html code from an email into a div on a webpage.

The problem is that the styles of the email are overriding the overall website styles.  So if an email has a red background then my entire site's background color is red.

How do I lock the inner html of the div that has the email html.

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML/CSS in the e-mail?

Comment: I have the entire html from <html></html>.  I going to display many different emails and they'll all have their own css.

Answer (score 2):

You need to address this issue by re-writing or fixing your CSS, otherwise do something like load the HTML email as an **iframe** and the contents will be isolated from the rest of the page.

Its simply **pollution**, you mix one set of CSS with another, they mix, and cause problems.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using iframes because i want google to be able to spider the content.  Rewriting css is working but i'll have to make a style for every element on the page that i'm using in case an email might have a style that might override it.

Comment: If you cannot use an iframe, you might consider parsing the email stylesheet and munging it. This is how GMail does it, for example.

Comment: not sure how to parse or what munging it.  will have to google it to figure out.  Thanks

Comment: i do want the div displaying the email to show up properly styled.  Will parsing and munging affect that?